# are there any initiatives to work wordpress as microservices?

Tags: api

I wanted to know if there was any initiatives private or not to transform wordpress onto microservices.

As you know wordpress has a lot of great stuff, and it works.
But it's a monolithic code, and it's hard to tweek it to make it faster,
find issues, etc.

Opposed to a microservices where each api has it's own database, and it's own server.

Of course it's harder to set it up, but it's always going to be scalable and easier to find bottlenecks and to change parts of the code without affecting anything else

[image: Here is an image ilustrating some differences]

Here is a versus on how it should look

[image: Monolithic vs microservices]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: probably not on topic, but what does it even mean? not everybody is familiar with all the buzzwords, please extend the question or at least suplly a link to a definition

Comment: @MarkKaplun I will add it :), microservices is a way to go away from monolithic development, which allows to teams to concentrate on their stuff and quickly change stuff (languages, or anything) it's basically working api first

Comment: Oh i doubt it would be possible to do this. You can't even change a simple suffix for images in wordpress. It is an open source software, however it's core is even worse than a closed source app, it's can't be changed (because of updates, security, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

No, without going into too much ranting, the wordpress core philosophy is based on user experience and API stability, this kind of restructuring is impossible without "breaking some eggs" so I don't imagine core wordpress to go that direction in any time soon.

In addition, it doesn't make much sense for anything smaller than google/amazon/facebook (ok, I am exaggerating somewhat). The cost in performance will be staggering for the site hosted on a shared host and even for small VPS it will be just cost with not much benefit.

OTOH there is an effort to provide json based rest API, so at least the UI can be run as a totally separate system. Maybe other parts will follow.... but it is hard to imagine right now what other parts of the wordpress core might be a standalone subsystem.